# Adding a Yocto project to my SVN

Tags: svn, yocto

I'm new to Yocto/Poky/Bitbake.

I'm working on a project, creating a Linux+RootFS+App for an embedded device.

It's based on the Atmel SAMA5D3 chip, and my reference is their Yocto environment (BSP layer, but the standard Yocto jethro cloned from git).
The detailed instructions are [here](http://www.at91.com/linux4sam/bin/view/Linux4SAM/Sama5d3xekMainPage).

**My question:** How do I 'hold' the project within my SVN? Or do I???

Obviously, my application, drivers, etc. must be checked-in, but what about the Kernel sources, the RootFS + Utilities sources - which are standard?

If I later add a package - that would probably be in my custom recipe, so that'll be easy to follow.

As you see from the question - I'm not sure I'm even asking the correct questions...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rami,

I battled with your question myself a little over a year ago and while I am not sure this is the correct way it is how I am doing it and it seems to be working quite well.

My project involves a Raspberry Pi so I added the meta-raspberrypi BSP in the same folder as the Yocto project (by git cloning the BSP project into the Yocto folder).

On top of that I have created a few layers with my own code or adaptations of other projects that I want to include (e.g. hostapd, WiFi drivers, kernel changes etc). Those layers (named meta-*) also live alongside the standard Yocto directories and are under source control (in my case git), with a separate git repository for each layer.

My build directory is in the same Yocto directory but the only files that I need to maintain there are the configuration files (local.conf and bblayers.conf). I hardly every change those files so I have just copied those to a safe location. The rest of the contents in my build directory can be regenerated from scratch.

I guess it is possible to make more changes to the resulting image by modifying files in the build directory but I have tried to avoid that with the expressed aim of being able to version control my project.

As for the external components (the Raspberry Pi BSP and Yocto itself) I haven't seen a clear need to put them under source control. I happily assume that they will be available and all changes to them are in my own layers.

I hope that helps.

Comment: are the external components (Yocto, BSP, packages) TAGs (specific versions)?
Or, for example, checking-out and building the project in a few months will download a newer version of any component?

Comment: My projects are in constant change and I have not (yet) had any real need to backtrack. But what I do is that I have a small bash script that outputs the branch and the sha1 value for each layer included in my build. I then save that information together with my built image. Since a tag is basically just the sha1 value it should allow me to go back to the previous state - both for my own repositories and those for the external repositories (Yocto, BSP etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the uboot and kernel files. You can add a new machine recipe following the Yocto manual [Here on Section 5.4](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.0/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#platdev-newmachine) . This section will tell Yocto what to do to compile an image for your machine.

The wandboard I am using is based on [fsl-community-bsp](http://freescale.github.io/#) that uses Standard Kernel and uboot from the community.

You can find more information about from this [tutorial](http://www.jumpnowtek.com/wandboard/Wandboard-Systems-with-Yocto.html) in which he uses Standard Stable Linux Kernel.

Not sure if that answered your question.